# Aggregate function to extract all fields based on maximum date

Tags: postgresql

In one table I have duplicate values ​​that I would like to group and export only those fields where the value in the "published_at" field is the most up-to-date (the latest date possible). Do I understand it correctly as I use the MAX aggregate function the corresponding fields I would like to extract will refer to the max found or will it take the first found in the table?

Let me demonstrate you this on simple example (in real world example I am also joining two different tables). I would like to group it by id and extract all fields but only relating to the max published_at field. My query would be:

```
SELECT "t1"."id", "t1"."field", MAX("t1"."published_at") as "published_at"
FROM "t1"
GROUP By "t1"."id"

| id | field     | published_at |
---------------------------------
| 1  | document1 | 2022-01-10   |
| 1  | document2 | 2022-01-11   |
| 1  | document3 | 2022-01-12   |
```

The result I want is:
`1 - document3 - 2022-01-12`

Also one question - why am I getting this error "*ERROR: column "t1"."field" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function*". Can I use MAX function on string type column?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the latest row for each `id`, you can use `DISTINCT ON`. For example:

```
select distinct on (id) *
from t
order by id, published_at desc
```

If you just want the latest row in the whole result set you can use `LIMIT`. For example:

```
select *
from t
order by published_at desc
limit 1
```